# FileException exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB)

Tags: sql, laravel, phpmyadmin

This is confusing beacuse

in my **php.ini** file it says

> post_max_size:512M, upload_max_filesize:256M

in **php settings** it says

> post_max_size:512M, upload_max_filesize:256M

and in **phpinfo()** it says

> post_max_size:512M, upload_max_filesize:256M

So I still don't get where the issue is.

P.s it worked before but then wamp crashed and then I re-installed it and ever since then I have been getting this issue

Comment: I'm not sure, but search limit in UploadFile class

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm using wampserver